# using colspan with nested html tables

Tags: html

I have a html table that looks like this:

[image]

It's created as a single table like this:

```
<table border=1 frame=void cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4>
<tr><th colspan=20 align=center><h2>Limits</h2></th></tr>
<tr>
<th colspan=6></th>
<th colspan=6>Position Limits</th>
<th colspan=4>Aim Order Limits</th>
<th colspan=4>Actual Order Limits</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan=6></th>
<th colspan=2>Book</th>
<th colspan=2>Product</th>
<th colspan=2>Cluster</th>
<th colspan=2>Buy</th>
<th colspan=2>Sell</th>
<th colspan=2>Buy</th>
<th colspan=2>Sell</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Cluster</th>
<th>Symbol</th>
<th>Ticker</th>
<th>Market</th>
<th>MaxShort</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
<th>Min</th>
<th>Max</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ALE-EU</td>      
<td>aleCHF</td>
     ,
     ,
     .
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to make these nested tables so that I can have a specific class on the inner most table (the one with the "Product, Cluster, ..." header row. The problem I am having is that the outer tables don't respect the columns of the inner tables, so the colspans are not correct. I've tried it all kinds of different ways with no success. This is my current markup:

```
<table border=1 frame=void cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 style="width: 100%;">
<tr><th colspan=20 align=center><h2>Limits</h2></th></tr>
<tr>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=6></th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=6>Position Limits</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=4>Aim Order Limits</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=4>Actual Order Limits</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border=1 frame=void cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4>
<tr>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=6></th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Book</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Product</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Cluster</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Buy</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Sell</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Buy</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom colspan=2>Sell</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="sortable" border=1 frame=void cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Product</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Cluster</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Symbol</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Ticker</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Market</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>MaxShort</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Min</th>
<th align=center valign=bottom>Max</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AMID</td>    
     .
     .
     .
```

And my table comes out like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can create this as nested tables and maintain the same colspans as when it was a single table?

Comment: Does it have to be nested tables? Could you not use classes on the individual cells as needed?

Comment: The sorting package we use requires that the class be on the table to be sorted and it will make the headers rows clickable for sorting.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using a nested table to get the desired look.  I would look into the sorting package you're using - can you not customize what it uses as headers?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought, but I was having trouble getting that working. We have lots of different tables to sort, and some just have a normal single header row, so I'd either have to pass in some flag to tell it which header row to use for sorting, or have different code for different tables. If I can't do it with nested tables I'll have to revisit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using one table and putting all the header rows in a  and then modifying the js sorting code to use the last rows of the thead.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try using a single table and concatenate the headers like in the code below? I think this should serve what you are looking for, semantically. I don't know if you could then style the added spans via CSS to get the desired look of colspans, just an idea...

```
<table class="sortable">
    <tr>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>Product</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>Cluster</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>Symbol</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>Ticker</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>Market</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>MaxShort</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Position Limit</span>
            <span>Book</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Position Limit</span>
            <span>Book</span>
            Max</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Position Limits</span>
            <span>Product</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Position Limits</span>
            <span>Product</span>
            Max</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Position Limits</span>
            <span>Cluster</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Position Limits</span>
            <span>Cluster</span>
            Max</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Buy</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Buy</span>
            Max</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Sell</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Sell</span>
            Max</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Buy</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Buy</span>
            Max</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Sell</span>
            Min</th>
        <th align=center valign=bottom>
            <span>Aim Order Limits</span>
            <span>Sell</span>
            Max</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AMID</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the users do not like that format. Thanks anyway.